# React todo list. addItem function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm following a tutorial to make a React todo app.
I have components and contexts files.
I have addItem function but when I clicked 'Add todo' button,
the item and date is not rendering into todo list.
Also, it shows an error as Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. even though
I have given an id.

Since I am following the tutorial, I don't know where I did wrong.
Would be appreciated if anyone could tell what is wrong.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import Form from './components/Form';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import TodoContextProvider from './contexts/TodoContexts';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <TodoContextProvider>
          <Navbar />
          <TodoList />
          <Form />
        </TodoContextProvider>

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

TodoContexts.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export const TodoContext = createContext();

const TodoContextProvider = (props) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {items: 'laundry', date: '2020-11-18', id: 1},
    {items: 'lunch', date: '2020-11-20', id: 2}
  ]);

  const addItems = (items, date) => {
    setItems([...items, {items, date, id: uuidv4()}]);
  };

  const removeItems = (id) => {
    setItems(items.filter(item => item.id !== id));
  };

  return (
    <TodoContext.Provider value={{ items, addItems, removeItems }}>
      {props.children}
    </TodoContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default TodoContextProvider
```

TodoList.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import TodoDetails from './TodoDetails';
import { TodoContext } from '../contexts/TodoContexts';

const TodoList = () => {
  const { items } = useContext(TodoContext);
  return items.length ? (
    <div className="todo-list">
      <ul>
        {items.map(item => {
          return ( <TodoDetails item={item} key={item.id} /> )
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="empty">You have no todos at the moment.</div>
  )
}

export default TodoList
```

TodoDetails.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { TodoContext } from '../contexts/TodoContexts';

const TodoDetails = ({ item }) => { //TodoList item is props
  const { removeItems } = useContext(TodoContext);

  return (
    <li onClick={() => removeItems(item.id)}>
      <div className="items">{item.items}</div>
      <div className="date">{item.date}</div>
    </li>
  )
}

export default TodoDetails
```

Form.js

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import './Form.css';
import { TodoContext } from '../contexts/TodoContexts';

const Form = () => {
  const {addItems} = useContext(TodoContext);
  const [items, setItems] = useState('');
  const [date, setDate] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(items, date);
    addItems(items, date);
    setItems('');
    setDate('');
  }

  return (
      <form className="form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

        <input
          type="text"
          value={items}
          placeholder="Enter todo"
          onChange={(e) => setItems(e.target.value)}
        />

        <input
          type="date"
          value={date}
          onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
        />

        <input type="submit" value="Add todo"/>

      </form>
  )
}

export default Form
```

Navbar.js

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { TodoContext } from '../contexts/TodoContexts';

const Navbar = () => {
  const { items } = useContext(TodoContext);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
      <p>Currently you have {items.length} todos to get through...</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navbar
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error may be attributable to using same variable name of 'items' in addItems function:

Try changing the name of first argument to 'item' instead.

```
 const addItems = (item, date) => {
    setItems([...items, {item, date, id: uuidv4()}]);
  };
```